# How to monitor subscription status upon app launch (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm building a simple dating app that allows a user to become premium with an auto-renewing subscription. The user's value for their "isPremium" attribute is false upon creating an account, and becomes true once they purchase a subscription via an in-app purchase. But I have to implement one more thing to finish this premium feature, and this is where I run into problems!

How do I monitor the app's current user's subscription status when the app launches? I want to keep their "isPremium" attribute true if their subscription is still ongoing, but immediately change it to false if it has expired.

I'm aware this has probably already been asked on here, but responses are mixed and mostly in Obj-C (I'm building this app in Swift). Would the best move be a backend server in Python to validate receipts? Or is there a simpler, more direct way of getting an expiration date from a subscription product object or a Cocoapod that handles this backend work? Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best move is a backend server like you mentioned. This way you store the receipt file there and periodically refresh it with Apple, so you always know the subscription status for any user.

On the device, you request the subscription status from your server and cache it (~5min). Every time the user resumes or opens your app check if the cache is stale and refresh it. This way you can prevent expired users from retaining access for more than 5mins yet keep it fast and snappy on app launch.

> Or is there a simpler, more direct way of getting an expiration date
>   from a subscription product object or a Cocoapod that handles this
>   backend work? Please help!

If you're looking for an out of the box solution, RevenueCat is a solid option and handles **all** of the backend work. They have a free tier as well. https://github.com/revenuecat/purchases-ios